# If value in one cell, then modify row which consists that cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am totally new to VBA and I am struggling a little bit with one thing. I want to make a macro, which checks values in "M" column. If value is higher than 5, then print "hello". If not then print "x". Unfortunately, I only gets "x" back in selected cells.

```
Private Sub costam()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 13

For i = 1 To Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(a, i).Value > 5 Then
     Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(10, i)).Value = "hello"
    Else
     Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(10, i)).Value = "x"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I know this problem is silly and takes like 1 minute to solve, but I am trying to apply some alike problems but without any progress.

Comment: `If Cells(i,a) ...` and switch the others correspondingly, its row then column.

Comment: @SJR omg, thank you!

Comment: The real solution to your question was @SJR comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom function for this workbook.

```
Public Function CustomFunction(myVal As Integer)
Dim myResult As String

If myVal > 5 Then
    myResult = "Hello"
Else
    myResult = "X"
End If

    CustomFunction = myResult
End Function
```

Then, you would write a formula in the cell where you want the value to be returned. 
`=CustomFunction(A2)`

Your custom function will need to be placed into a module.
[Excel VBA User-Defined Functions Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw49th_5ZDU)